# How to set Gradient color for statusbar

Tags: swift3, cagradientlayer

Code:

```
extension UIApplication {
    class var statusBarBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return (shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView)?.backgroundColor
        } set {
            (shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView)?.backgroundColor = newValue
        }
    }
}

UIApplication.statusBarBackgroundColor = .blue
```

I am trying to set gradient colour for status bar alone.How to change my code to set gradient colour.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean only status bar or statusbar+navigation bar?

Comment: statusbar only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I manage it.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:-20, width:375, height:64)
    let colorTop = UIColor(red: 69/255, green: 90/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 44/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    gradientLayer.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:-20, width:375, height:self.view.frame.height * 0.06)

    let window: UIWindow? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (window?.frame.width)!, height: self.view.frame.height * 0.07)
    view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    window?.addSubview(view)
```

**That only add the gradient to the view behind the status bar**

Comment: since i am hiding navigation controller your solution not working

Comment: i have edited the answer as you are hiding navigation controller